# Mongoose remove an element from array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my spa schema.

```
const spaSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  contactNumbers: String,
  address: String,
  images: [String],
});
```

I want to delete the element in the images array where the element name is 'abc.jpg' and documant id is x. How do I achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not really sure about your question, so I will cover 2 options. On both, I will assume that you are making an update on the `spa` collection.

### 1) Removing the `images` field from the document

To totally remove the field `images` from the desired document you can use the [MongoDB $unset operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset), as:

Original document:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId('some_id'),
  name : 'abc.jpg',
  contactNumbers: '...',
  address: '...',
  images: ['...']
}
```

Update method:

```
Spa.update(
 { name : 'abc.jpg', _id : ObjectId('some_id') },
 { $unset : { images : null } }
);
```

That will result in the :

```
{
  _id : ObjectId('some_id'),
  name : 'abc.jpg',
  contactNumbers: '...',
  address: '...'
}
```

### 2) Removing one element within the `images` field

If you are trying to remove just one element with a specific value from the `images` array, you can use the [MongoDB $pull operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull), like:

Original document:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId('some_id'),
  name : '...',
  contactNumbers: '...',
  address: '...',
  images: ['123.jpg','abc.jpg','def.jpg']
}
```

Update method:

```
Spa.update(
 { _id : ObjectId('some_id') },
 { $pull : { images : 'abc.jpg' } }
);
```

That will result in the :

```
{
  _id : ObjectId('some_id'),
  name : '...',
  contactNumbers: '...',
  address: '...',
  images: ['123.jpg','def.jpg']
}
```

I hope that is what you looking for.  =]

Comment: Thanks a lot. =)

Answer (score 1):

To remove one element from images(where you store image's name) you should use $pull as bellow

```
Spa.update(
 { _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId('some_id') },
 { $pull : { images : 'IMAGE_NAME_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_REMOVE_FROM_ARRAY' } }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. =)